# Can you 'or' with sscanf?

Tags: c++, arrays, scanf

Is there a way to delimit a char array using sscanf conditionally? For example

```
char arr[] = "abc def\tghi";
char s1[4];
char s2[4];
char s3[4];
std::sscanf(arr, "%s %s\t%s",s1,s2,s3);
```

but in a real example I do not know if (or where) it is separated by " " or "\t", it could be either, so I need it to be something such as

```
std::sscanf(arr, "%s " " or "\t"...");
```

where it checks for either a " " or a "\t"

Comment: Wait a second. Dusting off my C here. `scanf` shouldn't give a smurf what whitespace is used either. Lemme write a bit of hack test code.

Comment: Is the type of delimiter important? Does it need to be tab or space? Is there any significance to tab or space? Because as I slowly remembered, [`scanf` doesn't care](https://ideone.com/W3JFgq).

Comment: [No, it doesn't care](https://ideone.com/6FBeIe)

Comment: Side note: I'm kind of ashamed I wrote code to test that out when I could have just [looked it up](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf). See the second bullet point under **Parameters**

Comment: The more generic answer would be to parse a string using a `std::regex`, which explicitly allows `a|b` (a or b).